# Javascript function() inside an object previously declared: 'was called' event?

Tags: javascript

How to detect that getX is called, to trigger another function?

**Limitations**: `module` can be modified **only after its declaration**, because this object is received from a script loaded from a remote website. The goal is to tiger

**A.** This script is loaded from another website (`<script src="//remote.com/script.js">`)

```
var module = {
  x: 42,
  getX: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
}
```

**B.** This script is on my website `<script>...</script>`

```
when_getX_isExecuted function() {
    console.log('getX was executed');
}
```

Comment: Wrap the function with yours and reassign the property?

Comment: Ugly version: `module.getX = (() => { const getXCache = module.getX; return (...args) => { /* anything here */ getXCache(...args) };})();`, otherwise e.g. look into [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: @ASDFGerte would that not end in a endless loop? You could simply add the `return this.x` instead of the recall of `getX`

Comment: @wayneOS i had messed up the closure, and already had it edited, when you posted your comment. Reading the answer, i also notice i forgot to use `.call` instead of a direct invocation, losing proper `this`. But oh well, it's a comment to show the general idea :)

Comment: @wayneOS can you post your complete ugly solution?

Comment: @Slake I posted my answer. See for your self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to overwrite the old function and in the new function trigger whatever you want to trigger and then call the old function.

```js
var module = {
  x: 42,
  getX: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
};

function listenToFunction(object, propertyName, callBack) {
  var oldProperty = object[propertyName];
  if (typeof oldProperty !== "function") throw Error(`object.${propertyName} is not a function`);
  Object.defineProperty(object, propertyName, {
    value: function() {
      var params = [].slice.call(arguments);
      var result = oldProperty.apply(object, params);
      callBack(object, propertyName, params, result);
      return result;
    }
  });
}

console.log(module.getX()); // will not trigger
listenToFunction(module, "getX", function(object, propertyName, params, result) {
  console.log(`The function '${propertyName}' was called on the object ${JSON.stringify(object)}, with arguments ${JSON.stringify(params)}. The result was ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
});
console.log(module.getX()); // will trigger
console.log(module.getX(1, 2, 3)); // will trigger
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply override the function and add a call to your `when_getX_isExecuted` function. Here is an example. Hope it helps

```js
function when_getX_isExecuted () {
    console.log('getX was executed');
}

var module = {
  x: 42,
  getX: function () {
    return this.x;
  }
}

//override the function getX()
module.getX = function () {
  when_getX_isExecuted ();
  return this.x;
}

//test by calling getX()
var x = module.getX ();
console.log (x)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use prototype to pimp up code that's imported from third party.
[Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Object/prototype)